# Breaking Changes from Leiningen 2.2 -> 2.5

Tags: java, jar, clojure, compilation, leiningen

I have a `lein` project.  When I run this:

```
lein clean && lein deps && lein with-profile deploy compile
```

I see lots of class files etc, under `target/classes`, but when I run

```
lein jar
```

The class files are deleted and the resulting jar does not contain them, in fact it only has the `META-INF` directory and the `project.clj`.  What could be happening here?  My deploy profile looks like:

```
{:deploy {:jvm-opts ^:replace ["-Xmx1g"] :aot ^:replace [some.namespace]}
```

I've never seen or heard of this before, I am on Leingingen 2.5.0 and Clojure 1.5.1 and Google searches have yielded nothing.  What can I try next?

UPDATE: This issue does not occur in Lein 2.2 but it does in 2.5.  As additional info, 2.2 would produce the jar and the `provided` directory.  What breaking changes might have occurred?

UPDATE2: Changing the profile name from `:deploy` to `:provided` seems to fix the issue.

Comment: do you have an :aot entry in your project.clj?

Comment: Incidentally, you can use the `do` command to chain others, like so:
`lein with-profile deploy do clean, deps, deploy, compile`.  This also works inside `:aliases` in the project.clj, which is handy.

Answer (score 0):

Lein 2.5.0 has some known bugs regarding profiles. For now, I'd recommend using lein 2.4.x until the problems have been fixed.